# How to annotate only to a few instances in a queryset?

Tags: python, django

So I have a queryset of `Post` objects.  I want to annotate `user_voted` the `Post` objects that are created by a specific user.  In the end I want to send all the `Post` objects to the template, even those that are not annotated with `user_voted`.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Too hard.

Why not just query for all the post objects with the annotation and (if necessary) also the associated user (or maybe another annotation to control the display). In the template, conditionally display `{{obj.user_voted}}`

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
  stuff...

  <td> {% if obj.user.name == display_user %} {{obj.user_voted}} {%endif} </td>

{% endfor %}
```

It is probably possible to construct SQL via the Django ORM to evaluate conditions and set the annotation to a null string if the user is wrong. Don't ask me how. It will involve things like `F` expressions and `Case` and `Cast`. There is a place for this sort of complexity but I doubt this is it.

Sometimes it is easier to perform the logic of whether to display something in Python as a property method of the model, than in the template.

```
@property
def display_user_voted(self)
   return ... if ... else ''

{{ obj.display_user_voted }}
```